# Mercedes Benz- Atego truck indicator lamp not working

Tags: mercedes-benz, truck, lights

My Mercedes Benz Atego hit a cow and the right corner head lamp and indicator plus grill got damaged. I replaced the parts but now the right indicators have stopped working. What could be wrong and what is the solution?

Comment: Have you checked the wiring to the indicator? Use a multi-meter to ensure the wiring is working and check to see if the bulb has burned out.

Answer (score 1):

Is the fixture getting electricity? Have you tested it with a meter? If it is, your problem is possibly just a bad bulb.

If it isn't, then you have a wiring issue.. possibly a crimped or cut wiring harness, damaged during the collision. In that case, you're going to want to track it back to where it is severed, and repair it.

**EDIT**

And now that I read @PoissonFish's comment, this is nearly identical to what they said.